# React update props from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some trouble with updating information from my API with React.
For example, I have a js file that takes information about a client, after I change information about a client, for example balance, even if I click to another page and return information is not updated, only if I click F5 it will update info.

This is a file

```
class Portfolio extends Component {

  render() {
    const { authUser } = this.props;

    return (
      <Widget>
        <h2 className="h4 gx-mb-3">Your Portfolio Balance</h2>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>

            <div className="ant-row-flex">
              <h2 className="gx-mr-2 gx-mb-0 gx-fs-xxxl gx-font-weight-medium">{authUser ? authUser.balance : "Loading"}€</h2>
            </div>
            <p className="gx-text-grey"></p>
            <div className="ant-row-flex gx-mb-3 gx-mb-md-2">
              <Button className="gx-mr-2" type="primary">Deposit</Button>
              <Button className="gx-btn-red" disabled>Withdraw</Button>
            </div>
            <p><Link className="gx-text-primary" to="/te">- Messages <Badge count={23} style={{ backgroundColor: '#52c41a' }} /></Link></p>
            <p><Link className="gx-text-primary" to="/te">- Notifications <Badge count={320} style={{ backgroundColor: '#52c41a' }} /></Link></p>
            <p><Link className="gx-text-primary" to="/te">- Active Servers <Badge count={5} style={{ backgroundColor: '#52c41a' }} /></Link></p>
            <p><Link className="gx-text-primary" to="/te">- Billing </Link></p>
            <p><Link className="gx-text-primary" to="/te">- Logout </Link></p>


          </Col>
          <Col lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={24}>
            <div className="gx-site-dash">
              <h4 className="gx-mb-3">Welcome back {authUser ? authUser.username : "Loading"}</h4>
              <img alt="" width="160" src={authUser ? authUser.avatar : 'Loading'} />
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Widget>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  const { authUser } = auth;
  return { authUser }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userSignOut })(Portfolio);
```

Do I need to use WebSockets to make it live and don't need to refresh the page or there is easier way?

Edit:
Reducer

```
 const INIT_STATE = {
      token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')),
      initURL: '',
      authUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')),

    };

    export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {


        case INIT_URL: {
          return {...state, initURL: action.payload};
        }

        case USER_DATA: {
          return {
            ...state,
            authUser: action.payload,
          };
        }
```

Action:

```
export const getUser = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/details/profile',
    ).then(({ data }) => {
      if (data.username) {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_SUCCESS });
        dispatch({ type: USER_DATA, payload: data });
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: data.error });
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message });
      console.log("Error****:", error.message);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: From what You wrote it seems like what is happening is that fetching request works fine and gets the data correctly, but the function that updates the store in Redux (which I think You are using to store balance) doesn't do the job correctly. Can You show some code from request to updating the store.

Comment: Where are you updating the data? Via the UI or elsewhere? Where is the `getUser` method called from?

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct, your component need to be:
`class Portfolio extends PureComponent`

One of the main difference between `Component` and `PureComponent` is the update method for props.
`PureComponent` update when props change, `Component` don't update.

PureComponent handle `shouldComponentUpdate()` for you.

Comment: Already tried that, works same as Component. This is actuions.js how I handle that request.

Comment: export const getUser = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/details/profile',
    ).then(({ data }) => {
      if (data.username) {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_SUCCESS });
        dispatch({ type: USER_DATA, payload: data });
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: data.error });
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message });
      console.log("Error****:", error.message);
    });
  }
};

Comment: Can I see your reducer?